# Unable to obtain IP address of SOAP client in gSOAP server

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, jax-ws, gsoap

I am writing both a SOAP client and server, my server is in C++ using gSOAP 2.8.15 and my client is in Java, using JAX-WS 2.0.

When I connect from my client to my server, I would like to be able to see some information about the connection, specifically, what is the IP address of the client connected to my server. I did some research and saw it was possible to obtain this information from gSOAP by using something like the following:

```
printf ("starting session with %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
       (int) (soap->ip>>24) & 0xff,
       (int) (soap->ip>>16) & 0xff,
       (int) (soap->ip>>8) & 0xff,
       (int) soap->ip & 0xff);
```

However, this always prints out "0.0.0.0" without fail. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked that the contents of `soap->ip` isn't 0?

Comment: I have, and it is 0, which makes me think that it's unset. If that is the case, what do I need to toggle or flag to make sure it's set?

Comment: You probably need to go back and create the simplest example possible. Msybe at first create both client and server in C++ and check thst `soap->ip` is set. And ensure that you are actually making a connection.

Answer (score 0):

First,You can get current receive socket fd by soap->master,this fd means what connecting with client，make sure you soap use tcp, then you can use getsockname() to get local ip address and getpeername get peer address.

my gsoap version is 2.8.9

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct, provided that a client has actually connected. Per the [gSOAP docs](https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/structsoap.html):

> `unsigned int soap::ip`
>
> The IPv4 address in numeric form of the client as received on the server side by `soap_accept` (or the C++ service class `accept` method), possibly set to zero when `WITH_IPV6` is used.